# Ionic v3 polyfill.js Uncaught promise error

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ionic3

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YeaD.png)

Do you guys have any idea why am I constantly getting this error? I couldn't debug because I don't see anything in my about my code in the stack and my app is working as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try to go to `Index.html` and put the `polifill.js` library before `cordoba.js` library:

```
<script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>

 <script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Comment: Tried but did not work. got the error that says "Runtime Error: Zone already loaded."

Comment: that happens when you are loading the same module 2 times. look for duplicities in your imports